# How to show page number in category page?

Tags: pagination, numbers, generator, categories

My page of categories not have option of limiting the post numbers, also not permit that this page to be paginated. I tried put the respective code that generate the pagination in other place as Query posts, in page.php, but no work:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'includes/pagination'); ?>
```

I tried insert this code here:

query_category)); ?>               


 isset( $category ) && isset( $category->term_id )? $category->term_id : 0, 'orderby' => 'id' ) ); ?>

```
<?php foreach($cats as $cat): ?>                    
<?php query_posts( apply_filters( 'themify_query_posts_page_args', 'cat='.$cat->cat_ID.'&posts_per_page='.$themify->posts_per_page.'&paged='.$themify->paged.'&order='.$themify->order.'&orderby='.$themify->orderby ) );   ?>

                <?php if(have_posts()): ?>

                    <!-- category-section -->
                    <div class="category-section clearfix <?php echo $cat->slug; ?>-category">                         
                        <h3 class="category-section-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link($cat->cat_ID) ); ?>" title="<?php _e('View more posts', 'themify'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a></h3>

                        <!-- loops-wrapper -->
                        <div id="loops-wrapper" class="loops-wrapper <?php echo $themify->layout . ' ' . $themify->post_layout; ?>">                            
                        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <?php get_template_part('includes/loop', 'query'); ?>

                        <?php endwhile;?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /loops-wrapper -->
```